# Does the rule of not staying out late at night because jinns are more active during that time apply to teenagers as well?

Tags: sharia, jinn

I understand that children are to be kept inside after dusk because the jinns become more active during that time.

Does that ruling apply to teenagers as well? Even if the person is not out around town, but in front of a friends house?

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. Good question. Please also go through the guidelines provided in [ask].

Answer (score 5):

The rule is not only for teenagers but to everyone, and applies to children in particular.

Here's a good link with a detailed explanation: http://islamqa.info/en/125922

From it we see that we should observe the following:

1. Close your doors and windows and remain indoors
2. Tie up your water-skins - in our times, we have jars or containers.
3. Turn off your lamps when going to bed.
4. Keep food covered.

On a different note, if you don't have a valid reason to go out at night, just remain at home. If you're a teen, here are some things you can do during the night without wasting time in front of your friends' homes.

1. Clean up your house - at least your room.
2. Help your parents with their house work and their affairs.
3. Recite the Qur'an
4. Study something - it could be Islamic or related to your studies.
5. If you have younger siblings, teach them something.
6. You have plenty to do. If not, just go to bed early and this may help getting up early for the morning prayer, insha Allaah.